# Set output build path for Visual Studio 2017 per user with vars

Tags: c#, msbuild, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-2017-build-tools

I am trying to change the output path for build per user. I want to redirect output to Ram Disk. After many attempts i finished with something like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputPath>R:\VisualStudioBuilds\MyProjectName\bin\$(Configuration)\</OutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

But the project name is hardcoded! To change this situation i have tried another solution:

```
<OutputPath>R:\VisualStudioBuilds\$(ProjectName)\bin\$(Configuration)\</OutputPath>
```

And this doesn't work. In the end the build path is `R:\VisualStudioBuilds\bin\Debug`. I have also tried out another variables like `ProjectDir`, `RootNameSpace` and other but still no success.

What should I do to make it work? Remember, any modification should be in .csproj.user not to team-shared .csproj.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What should I do to make it work? **Remember, any modification should be in .csproj.user not to team-shared .csproj**.

Sorry for this delayed reply, but hope this can give you some helps.

To accomplish this issue, you can use property **`$(AssemblyName)`** instead of `$(ProjectName)`, so the settings in the `.csproj.user` looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputPath>R:\VisualStudioBuilds\$(AssemblyName)\bin\$(Configuration)\</OutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

That should be works for you.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. In fact, build is done in selected folder, but Visual Studio still is trying to start app from `R:\VisualStudioBuilds\bin\Debug\`. This makes the solution useless.

Comment: Indeed, with this settings, when you run your app, you will get some error. But this should be another question, you can open a new thread for debugging of this issue.

Comment: Okay, so i have opened a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52716550/visual-studio-is-trying-to-run-app-from-different-path-than-specified-in-csproj). If you can help i will be thankfull.

Comment: @Mikołaj, OK, I will investigate this issue when I free :).

Answer (score 0):

The default output directory is :

```
$(SolutionDir)$(Configuration)\
```

So by default, output binaries will be created in:

```
Path\To\Your\Solution\[Configuration]\.
```

Configuration can be something like "Debug" or "Release".

Depending on your project settings, these directories can vary. You can see/change those settings in :

```
Menu Project -> Properties -> Configuration Properties -> General -> Output Directory
```